# Overlapping images and kCGBlendMode

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have 4 pngs that have some transparency and they need to be placed on top of one another and pixels need to come through from the images.

So the pixels on the same position in the images need to be blended.

Which blend mode should I use? Also, I add these images as subviews, where would I set the blend mode? I have seen it set in the drawRect, but this is surely incorrect. Should it be in the init method? The class is a UIView subclass.

```
// done in drawRect
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear);
```

Will those image subviews be inside the current context or will applying a blend mode not effect the images?

Comment: Blend mode works while drawing the images into a context, not while placing different subviews with different content. You'll need to look through the blend modes to decide which is correct for your needs (Apple docs show example images for what each does).

Comment: I just updated my question with the subview issue as you were writing the comment. So what if I needed to run animations on these images? How would I reference them if rendered in the context? How do I render them in the context?

Comment: You render them into a context by using `CGDrawImage` inside of a view's `drawRect`.

Comment: Will animations be applied to them if I run them on the pointer reference?

Comment: No, animating them will be clumsy and probably slow.

Comment: So, It cannot be done to animate them and apply blend modes?

Comment: It can, you just need to handle the animations yourself (i.e. with actual numbers and timers instead of UIView animations).

Comment: The problem is I need it to animate and in real time update the animations smoothly. I asked this earlier -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787798/updating-running-animations-smoothly